# How to upload and download images into server from android using phpmyadmin and json?

Tags: android, json, eclipse, phpmyadmin

I mean, to my **local host** database.

Please help me.

Comment: There is no question in your post.

Comment: I need complete android code for this.

Comment: Please read about [how to ask good questions](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to edit your question. Also don't get your hopes up about the code, **Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service**. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Find this link.It contain both code of Android and Php for image uploading. 
http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/android-uploading-camera-image-video-to-server-with-progress-bar/

**Image Downloading:**

call this method in onCreate and mImageUrl is your url to download image

new DownloadImage().execute(mImageUrl);

```
class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    showDialog(progress_bar_type);
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... mImageUrl) {
    int count;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(mImageUrl[0]);
        URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
        conection.connect();
        // getting file length
        int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

        // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

        // Output stream to write file
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/downloadedImage.jpg");

        byte data[] = new byte[1024];

        long total = 0;

        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;
            // publishing the progress....
            // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
            publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));

            // writing data to file
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }

        // flushing output
        output.flush();

        // closing streams
        output.close();
        input.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
    }

    return null;
}


  protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
    // setting progress percentage
    pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
 }


 @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(String mImageUrl) {
    // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
    dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);

    // Displaying downloaded image into image view
    // Reading image path from sdcard
    String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/downloadedImage.jpg";
    // setting downloaded into image view
    my_image.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(imagePath));
}

}

 @Override
   protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case progress_bar_type: // we set this to 0
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Downloading file. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setMax(100);
        pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
        return pDialog;
    default:
        return null;
    }
}
```